# Java access to windows share with JCIFS vs Linux mount?

Tags: apache-camel, jcifs

I'm setting up an integration for transfering files to and from a windows fileshare using Apache Camel. 
For this I could use either https://camel.apache.org/jcifs.html or a plain file endpoint on a local samba mount (will be running on RHEL)

I would expect JCIFS to maybe incur a small performance cost, but that it would improve my control from the integration-setup, of transparent configuration and handling.

On the other hand, development on JCFIS seems to end in 2011.

Anyone with experience with JCFIS in this kind of setup? Or just insight into pros and cons compared to smbmount ?

Comment: I have used SAMBA with success that is all I can add. We mounted the windows share as a linux directory and it was like accessing a local directory. No major hassles to report.

Answer (score 1):

Major effort is made to make windows file shares mountable on *nix through the samba driver by RedHat developers among others. There where a new release a few days ago. Can't say the same about the subproject JCIFS - as you point out yourself - hasn't changed for many years.

If you ask for stability and security, this may be important.

That said, JCIFS works in many scenarios I've tested and shouldn't be ruled out for simple scenarios where portability is more important than stability, but I've heard stories about authentication problems using different JDK versions among other things.